# What am I doing wrong with this preparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

```
private Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, info);
try {
String sql = "INSERT INTO \"STUD1582251\".\"ACCOUNTS\" VALUES USERNAME=?, PASSWORD=?, PORTFOLIONAME=?";
    PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stm.setString(1, user.getUsername());
    stm.setString(2, user.getPassword());
    stm.setString(3, user.getPortfolioName());
    System.out.println(sql);
    stm.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception

> SELECT username FROM "STUD1582251"."ACCOUNTS" WHERE username=? INSERT
>   INTO "STUD1582251"."ACCOUNTS" VALUES USERNAME=?, PASSWORD=?,
>   PORTFOLIONAME=? java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL
>   command not properly ended

Comment: Posting the error stacktrace might help...

Comment: You know that you don't need the double quotes around column and table names?

Comment: There's a `SELECT` as well as a malformed `INSERT` statement concatenated together. Check how you're creating the SQL string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

INSERT SQL statement must be:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO \"STUD1582251\".\"ACCOUNTS\" (USERNAME,PASSWORD,PORTFOLIONAME) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

PS: Use " (double quotes) around *identifier* if it is a *reserved* word.